# How can I create a custom "Add to cart" form?

Tags: forms, commerce, 10

I'm developing a basic Commerce shop with Drupal 10.
The product type is *clothing*, which has a single product variation (*product_size*) and three different product attributes for that variation.

The whole site is based on *Custom Blocks* and *Views Blocks* where I can easily modify how the nodes and products are listed and displayed, but there is problem with the *Add to cart* form.

Is there a way to render a custom *Add to cart* form in a custom block with product attributes fields and reorder them, rather than changing from it from the *Manage display* section.

By changing and reordering, I mean the ability to load, for example, a product attribute which, when a user clicks, the price and quantity are changed or static labels and HTML markup are added.

I was able to load the *Add to cart* form in a custom block, but I can't load or reorder fields (price and other product variation fields).

```php
$commerceProduct = \Drupal::service('commerce_product.lazy_builders');
$cart_array = $commerceProduct->addToCartForm($product->id(), 'default', true, 'fa');
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($cart_array);
```

Basically, I need a method with a `$product_id` parameter which returns the render array for the *Add to cart* form.